# Horizontal text scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, horizontal-scrolling, scrolltrigger

Please help me solve the problem with horizontal text scrolling. I have text on my site wrapped in a '.zenno__slider-slide' class that doesn't fit completely on the screen. When scrolling down, it will scroll from right to left, and only when it is completely hidden, the user is able to scroll down. The only problem is that if the user scrolls the page quickly, the text does not have time to scroll and this moment does not work. Also, by design, the scroll down label should be located almost close to this text, but I can’t move it close to it because of the element with the ‘.pin-spacer’ class.

In general, the script itself works somehow strangely, sometimes with bugs. I implemented it using GSAP and ScrollTrigger. Please help me solve the problem. Maybe someone can suggest another solution for this functionality. I will be glad for any help. I leave the code below so you can see. Thanks in advance)

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".zenno__slider-slide");

gsap.to(sections, {
  xPercent: -200 * (sections.length - 1),
  ease: "none",
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".zenno__slider-wrapper",
    pin: ".zenno",
    pinSpacing: true,
    scrub: 20,
    end: "+=1000",
  },
});
```

```css
.zenno {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.zenno__slider-wrapper {
  width: 400%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.zenno__slider-slide {
  line-height: 50vh;
  width: 500%;
  margin-left: 10rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zenno__slider-slide p {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.zenno__container-subtitle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.625rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="zenno" id="zenno">
            <div class="zenno__slider-wrapper">
                <div class="zenno__slider-slide">
                    <p>Our name <strong> “Zenno” </strong> comes from a Japanese word <strong> “zennou” </strong> which
                        means:
                        almighty
                        or
                        omnipotent</p>
                </div>
                <div class="zenno__slider-slide"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zenno__container-subtitle wow animate__animated
                    animate__fadeInDown">
                <p>Scroll Down</p>
                <img src="img/arrow_down.svg" alt="arrow_down" width="16" height="25">
            </div>
        </section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
```